# Did a YT-1300 freighter make an appearance in The Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

In *Attack of the Clones* in the spaceport on Naboo we see a familiar looking ship landed in the spaceport.

[image]

and in *Revenge of the Sith* we see coming in another familiar looking ship:

[image]

While they both don't look exactly like the *Falcon*, ships of the same make and model have made appearances.  So my question is this: Did any YT-1300 freighter make an appearance in *The Phantom Menace*?

Comment: I have no idea where this ship you're referring to might be in the first picture.

Comment: @DCShannon cropped and added a freehand red circle.

Comment: There it is. That sure looks like a YT-1300 to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NO**

No YT-1300 freighter appears in *The Phantom Menace*.  Although many have looked for it, it isn't there.  Many easter egg sites died to bring me this information.

The ship in the second picture, from Revenge of the Sith, has been confirmed by George Lucas as actually being the Millennium Falcon.

There is a archived copy of the page that used to be on StarWars.com [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20050901000018/http://www.starwars.com/episode-iii/bts/production/f20050526/) (thanks to Adamant).

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon):

> It was speculated that the Falcon would make an appearance in Revenge of the Sith to further tie the prequel trilogy to the original trilogy, and the ship did indeed make a cameo in the movie. At the beginning of one shot closing in on a docking bay on Coruscant, a freighter is seen flying in to dock. George Lucas confirmed that it was the Millennium Falcon itself and not just another ship of the same class.

Comment: OK, sure…but the Falcon is indeed a YT-1300 freighter. Also, a link to Lucas’s statements about this (as opposed to Wookieepedia) would be helpful.

Comment: @Adamant - I never said the Falcon wasn't a YT-1300.  Also the StarWars.com easter egg hunt page that had Lucas' quote has been removed, and I can't find an archive copy.  But Wookiepedia is endorsed by StarWars.com, so is good enough IMO.

Comment: Ah, OK, my mistake. I thought you were talking about RotS. But (endorsed by SW.com or not) Wookieepedia has been known to contain mistakes, and primary sources are better than secondary in any case.

Comment: @Adamant - if you can find an original source I'd be happy to add it.  But I can't find one.

Comment: This is a backup of the page in question: http://web.archive.org/web/20050901000018/http://www.starwars.com/episode-iii/bts/production/f20050526/. That should do the trick.

Comment: If the first picture in the question is from the Phantom Menace, then how do you explain the YT-1300 freighter that is in it?

Comment: @DCShannon - it's clearly stated in the question (and in all other sources) that the picture is from Attack of the Clones.

Comment: @Tim Oh, yep, you're right. That's confusing. Now I wish I could retract my upvote on the question.