# Is the Millennium Falcon seen in Attack of the Clones?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, millennium-falcon

After reading this question: [Did a YT-1300 freighter make an appearance in The Phantom Menace?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149947/did-a-yt-1300-freighter-make-an-appearance-in-the-phantom-menace), it appears that the Millennium Falcon was shown in Revenge of the Sith. However, we can also see that there is a YT-1300 freighter in Attack of the Clones:

[image: YT-1300 freighter in Attack of the Clones]

Is this the Millennium Falcon or just another YT-1300 freighter?

Comment: It looks very different from the falcon. The cockpit isn't in the same place as the Falcon, also it looks like there is no dish (though that could have been added in later).

Comment: This is probably already answered here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149947/did-a-yt-1300-freighter-make-an-appearance-in-the-phantom-menace?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did a YT-1300 freighter make an appearance in The Phantom Menace?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149947/did-a-yt-1300-freighter-make-an-appearance-in-the-phantom-menace)

Comment: But the short answer is No.  The one seen in that pic is the same model freighter, but it is _not_ the Falcon.

Comment: @Tim on looking closer it doesn't look exactly the same but provide evidence and write up an answer! And that question doesn't answer this question which is want got me thinking to ask this one, if it had answered it why would I have asked this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In another shot you can actually see there are two ships on the left side that appear to be YT-1300s.

[image]

So, it is positive that *one* of them is just another YT-1300.

**As for the other one, probably not.** There are a lot of sites that say the YT-1300 seen in *Revenge of the Sith* has been confirmed by Lucas to be what will eventually be called the Millennium Falcon. But he never made such a confirmation on either of these two YT-1300s from *Attack of the Clones*.

In fact, the often quoted (and yet never cited) claim from Lucas goes something like this:

> George Lucas confirmed that it was the Millennium Falcon itself **and not just another ship of the same class.** - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon#Behind_the_scenes

YT-1300s were probably more common before the rein of the Empire.

Comment: [Citation](http://web.archive.org/web/20080213081905/www.starwars.com/episode-iii/bts/production/f20050526/)

Comment: @JasonBaker But they are just saying what everyone else says, there is no link to a transcript or interview or anything that actually quotes Lucas as saying that.

Comment: Not untrue, but it does come from the official site so [YMMV](https://media.giphy.com/media/130d6vlmqNcqxG/giphy.gif). I'd assume it came from a private conversation for creating that page